# When $x_n\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Fixing $\gamma, \gamma'$ two reals numbers such that 
$$|\gamma'|<\frac{1}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad 0<\gamma<1,$$
and,  $\alpha,\beta\in (0,\pi)$,  define
$$x_n=\sin\left(2\pi n\gamma+\alpha+\beta\right)+\sin\left(2\pi n\gamma'+\alpha-\beta\right)$$

Could someone give me a simple statement equivalent to $x_n\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

use that $$\sin(x)+\sin(y)=2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, and then? because I tried to do that.